# WCF service behaves differently at different server for Authentication standpoint

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, authentication, esb

We have an ESB service which our web application is consuming via WCF.

We tried to deploy web application at two different servers and the same service behave correctly at one server whereas not working in another server and getting following error. Here the service is wsHttpBinding.

The caller was not authenticated by the service

### Config

```
  <endpoint address="http:/server/service.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync" contract="contractDetails" name="WSHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="Domain\Userid@domain.subdomain"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>


    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="500" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Comment: The caller was not authenticated by the service. Please help.. It need  urgent fix

Comment: A screen shot with the error message could be more useful. I sugggest that you provide some related code sample too, in case the problem is not in the configuration. Do you have a stacktrace of any kind to provide us with?